# Is Purebond the only formaldehyde-free plywood?

Tags: plywood, health-and-safety

I have a few small projects need to use plywood. My concern is that most of plywoods contain formaldehyde. I heard [Purebond](http://purebondplywood.com/) is formaldehyde free. what are the pros and cons of Purebond? Is there any other plywood that is formaldehyde free?

Comment: It's a fair question, but keep in mind that "it's the dose that makes the poison". Formaldehyde is a naturally-occurring substance that exists in your body at all times. "A few small projects" are unlikely to cause you any harm unless you already have respiratory ailments. Studies of long-time factory workers don't even show positive correlation with illness.

Comment: @isherwood, thanks. but I am going to build  beds for kids and myself. It just make me uncomfortable to use materials contain formaldehyde. just to avoid it if I could.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, your question falls close to the "product recommendation" category, which is discouraged. Give the ol' search engine a workout.